# Getting base class of a method invocation in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I can identify method calls and invocations inside the methods of each class of an application. However, how can I get on which class they are called or invoked?

In the following code, for instance:

```
var methodDeclarations = classitem.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach (var memmeth in methodDeclarations)
{

    var varInvocations = memmeth.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
    foreach (InvocationExpressionSyntax invoc in varInvocations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---- Invocations---");
        Console.WriteLine(invoc.Expression);  // output: b1.ADD
        Console.WriteLine(invoc.Expression.Parent.GetText()); // output: b1.ADD(2)
    }
}
```

I can get, for example, as output "b1.ADD" and "b1.ADD(2)". What I need to extract from this is that ADD is called on b1 which is an instance of class B. How can I get this B class from the invocations in the code above? In other words, I need to tell to which class type this method belongs. How can I do that?

Comment: Does the `InvocationExpressionSyntax` contain a `MemberBindingExpressionSyntax` and does the `MemberBindingExpressionSyntax` contain any diagnostics (`membind.GetDiagnostics()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all! Here is the solution that does the job; not sure though if it is the best solution and an elegant one:

```
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var methodDeclarations = classitem.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach (var memmeth in methodDeclarations)
{

    var varInvocations = memmeth.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
    foreach (InvocationExpressionSyntax invoc in varInvocations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---- Invocations---");
        Console.WriteLine(invoc.Expression);  // output: b1.ADD
        Console.WriteLine(invoc.Expression.Parent.GetText()); // output: b1.ADD(2)
        var invokedSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(invoc).Symbol;
        Console.WriteLine(invokedSymbol.ToString()); //AppTest.B.ADD(int)
        Console.WriteLine(invokedSymbol.ContainingSymbol); //AppTest.B
        Console.WriteLine(invokedSymbol.ContainingSymbol.Name); //B  
    }
}
```

The last line gets the class name of the invoked method (as String) and prints it out.

Comment: This snippet is not complete, what is "compilation"?

Answer (score 1):

You need the Semantic Model, which allows you to access type information from the compiler (the syntax tree only looks at syntax in a file).

Specifically, you should call `GetSymbol()` on the `InvocationExpressionSyntax`, cast to `IMethodSymbol`, and look at its various properties.

Comment: `GetSymbol` on the `InvocationExpressionSyntax` will give you information about the method, including its `ContainingType`, but it won't tell you what the actual type of `b1` is. To get that, you need to call `GetTypeInfo` on `b1` itself.